# Storing a Variable in a .dat file

Tags: variables, batch-file

I am writing a simple batch script to compare what the user enters, to a line of text in a .dat (I can put it in a .txt file if necessary).

So far, I have a way of getting the user's input, using *set*:

```
set /P username=Please enter your Username: 
set /P given_password=Please enter your Password:
```

And the program navigates to the correct directory using *cd*:

```
cd C:\Users\Luke\Desktop\Dropbox\BATCH SERVER\USERS\%login_username%\
```

But now I need a way of reading the contents of the .dat file, and comparing it to what the user inputed (given_password)

Thanks in advance for any help,
-Luke

Edit:
More info on the .dat file:
The file is called config.dat. & is formatted like this, where **Geronimo** is the correct password.

```
password = Geronimo
```

I also plan to have other information stored in there, which I also would like to assign to variables later on in the script.

Comment: There are a number of ways to read through a file. Can you please upload how your .dat file is formatted. Does it simply contain one line which is what we need to compare. If so this is very easy. If not please give an example of what the .dat file contains. Furthermore, please describe the name of the .dat file.

Comment: @Monacraft I just updated the post with a little more information, but I will try out your solution now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `.dat` file simply contains one line defining the password to compare to, your batch file could simple be:

```
set /p "uname=Username: "
set /p "pass=Password: "
set /p comparepass=< "C:\Users\Luke\Desktop\Dropbox\BATCH SERVER\USERS\%login_username%\NAME.dat"
if "%pass%"=="%comparepass%" (
:: Insert code for when passwords are the same
) else (
:: Insert code for when passwords are not the same
)
```

And that should help you out.

Mona

Comment: Just had to reformat the .dat file slightly, and now this method works great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can parse the file like this:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims== " %%i in ('findstr "=" "ini.dat"') do set "%%i=%%j"
```

`findstr "=" "ini.dat"` will process only lines, that have  `=` in it. So you can store also Comments in the file like this:

```
This is the dat file
ist stores the username
user = Luke
and the password
password = Geronimo
and some other stuff...
```

EDIT:

`for` is used to do the same thing on several objects. For more info see `for /?`

Especially here:

`findstr "=" "ini.dat` finds all lines in the file `ini.dat` that contains `=`

The single qoutes around it `'` tells the `for`command to process the output of that command.

`in (`...`)` says: "For every of those found lines"

`"tokens=1,2 delims== "` says: "Take the first and second part (called "token") where they are separated by `=` or SPACE". (consecutive delimitors are treated as one)

The first part (Token) is assigned to a special variable `%%i`. As there is a second token, it is assigned to the following letter: `%%j`

`/f` tells the `for`command which syntax to use (see `for /?` for other possibilities)

`in (`...`)` says: "For every of those found lines"

`do set %%i=%%j` sets the variable (Token1 (= %%i ) to Token2 (= %%j)

Mona's way is better to understand and the preferable way, if there is only one "data" in the file. If there are more datasets (as you asked "I also plan to have other information stored in there") a `for`loop is the better way to go.

I know, this is hard stuff to understand, but it's worth the time spent. Try it with `echo on`, so you can see better, what it does.

Comment: Okay, Thanks. I will try this out now, but I'm new to batch and I am just wondering what each part of this command does. Any explanations would be appreciated. Thanks again.